# Azure Function Logging - Doubled Log-Entries?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, function, logging

I have noticed a strange behaviour which is not clear to me why this happens.

I have an Azure Function in which I am logging different things. For example I would Log a warning if a user in dynamics was not found:

```
Logger.Warning($"User '{user.Username}' was not found in CRM!");
```

So far so good. When I look into the Application Log I see that my custom log entry was some sort of doubled but with additional information. Look at the printscreen:

[image: printscreen]

You will see that there is a log entry like this (NOT done be me):

```
2020-02-26T10:18:08.415 [Warning,fnMyAzureFunction] User 'user1@xyz.com' was not found in CRM!
```

and below the one I made with above statement:

```
2020-02-26T10:18:08.415 [Warning] User 'user1@xyz.com' was not found in CRM!
```

So what surprises me is:

- where is the above log coming from?
- What is adding the function name to this additional log entry?
- how can this be that the time stamp of those different log entries are exactly the same?

From the code point of view it is impossible that the log part is executed twice. If this would happen the time stamp would never be exactly the same and also the logged text would be identical. There is no code in my function which adds the function name to the warning message. so this must be coming from "somewhere else".

Is there a setting which forces an additional log entry as soon a Log.Warning(..) statement is executed?

Any ideas? Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: what logger are you using? the injected ILogger instance inside your function? Please add some more code of your function if possible

Comment: The Logger is the default one which is passed into my run entry method (-> TraceWriter)

Comment: I was wondering because `Logger.` looks like something static you get from somewhere else?! Also, Tracewriter ounds like you are using an old version? The newer ones use ILogger

Comment: hmm...this could be the reason. I use an older version of the "functions" sdk...I'll check.